# Error running turtle module after setting background

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How do I fix an error that occured after setting the background when drawing with turtle?

I started to learn programming with the book "Head First Learn to Code". I have to make a module to make a turtle race with Python's turtle graphics. I followed the steps one by one, but when I tried to run the code, "syntax error" occured with the "setup()" line at the end of the code.

I compared my answer with the author's and every characters were the same. Then I copied and tried to run the author's code. When I tried to run the code, only a blank page appeared. In the code I have to set a background which is in the same directory as the module.

```
import turtle
import random

turtles = list()

def setup():
    global turtles
    startline = -620
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.setup(1290,720)
    screen.bgpic('pavement.gif')

    turtle_ycor = [-40, -20, 0, 20, 40]
    turtle_color = ['blue', 'red', 'purple', 'brown', 'green']

    for i in range(0, len(turtle_ycor)):
        new_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
        new_turtle.shape('turtle')
        new_turtle.penup()
        new_turtle.setpos(startline, turtle_ycor[i])
        new_turtle.color(turtle_color[i])
        new_turtle.pendown()
        turtles.append(new_turtle)

def race():
    global turtles
    winner = False
    finishline = 590

    while not winner:
        for current_turtle in turtles:
            move = random.randint(0,2)
            current_turtle.forward(move)

            xcor = current_turtle.xcor()
            if (xcor >= finishline):
                winner = True
                winner_color = current_turtle.color()
                print('The winner is', winner_color[0])

setup()
race()
turtle.mainloop()
```

I deleted the line `screen.bgpic('pavement.gif')` and the author's module worked well, but mine has the same same "syntax error". (Every character was the same, later I tried to copy-paste each part of the code and the error was the same).
How could I set that background pic?
The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/viccha/.cache/.fr-mVA9RC/headfirstlearntocode-master/ch7/race_step3.py", line 41, in <module>
    setup()
  File "/home/viccha/.cache/.fr-mVA9RC/headfirstlearntocode-master/ch7/race_step3.py", line 11, in setup
    screen.bgpic('pavement.gif')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 1481, in bgpic
    self._bgpics[picname] = self._image(picname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/turtle.py", line 479, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3545, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3501, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "pavement.gif": no such file or directory
```

Comment: Please show the whole sytanx error in your code

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me(except the part with race() because I don't have the function

You forgot to import the turtle module

```py
import turtle

def setup():
   global turtles
   startline = -620
   screen = turtle.Screen()
   screen.setup(1290,720)
   screen.bgpic('pavement.gif')

#the end of the code:

setup()
race()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: And? Also if you could paste here the error message that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The error message shown is caused by this line:

```
screen.bgpic('pavement.gif')
```

As you note, you can avoid the error by commenting out the line:

```
# screen.bgpic('pavement.gif')
```

Then your turtles should race just fine.  You can add that line back when/if you have a `pavement.gif` file available to use as the background image for the window.  A website associated with the book might provide it.  But for a program this simple, any GIF image of an appropriate size should work fine -- look on Google Images.

Comment: I have the pavement.gif in the same folder with the code. I tried to copy it to another folder, because the original one is a zip folder, but it didn't work